# Magento 2: replacement for the <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>, <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable> etc... product type specific layout handles

Tags: magento2, product, layout, update-handle

In Magento 1, we had some specific layout handles for each product types:

- `<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>`
- `<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>`
- `<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>`
- `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>`
- `<PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>`
- `<PRODUCT_TYPE_downloadable>`

It has been explained on this post that those handles were deprecated in Magento 2: [Magento2. Layout Handle customer_logged_in](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106134/magento2-layout-handle-customer-logged-in)

Question is: what do we use instead of those handles ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research here is what I've found.

In Magento 2, you can use the following layout files to handle product type specific pages:

- `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml`

Magento 2 adds this specific handle via the `initProductLayout` method of `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View` :

```
$resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(
        ['id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku, 'type' => $product->getTypeId()]
    );
```

In that particular case, the `addPageLayoutHandles` method adds the three following layout handle:

- `catalog_product_view_id_productid`
- `catalog_product_view_sku_productsku`

> Hey! that's a new handle that wasn't present on M1

- and finally `catalog_product_view_type_producttype`

Full detail of the `addPageLayoutHandles` method:

```
public function addPageLayoutHandles(array $parameters = [], $defaultHandle = null)
{
    $handle = $defaultHandle ? $defaultHandle : $this->getDefaultLayoutHandle();
    $pageHandles = [$handle];
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
        $pageHandles[] = $handle . '_' . $key . '_' . $value;
    }
    // Do not sort array going into add page handles. Ensure default layout handle is added first.
    return $this->addHandle($pageHandles);
}
```

On top of that, it will also support your custom product type for instance if you create a product type with the name "test" you can then create a file called `catalog_product_view_type_test.xml` to handle specific layouts for this type of products.