# Magento 2: Different layout for specific product?

Tags: magento2, product, layout

Is there a way to specify a layout (blocks in different positions and styled differently) for a specific product ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is two differents ways:

Using the product id in your layout, you can use the following layout handle to make modification to your page for this specific product:

```
<catalog_product_view_id_productid>
```

Or using the product sku, you can use the same method with the following layout handle:

```
<catalog_product_view_sku_productsku>
```

You may be interested in this post if you want to know more about how those handles are added to the layout: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/107462/2380

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, while adding the product go to `Advance Setting->Design` there you can set you own specific design

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted as this method does work.