# Different/Custom page layout for specific category/products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I encountered the situation where I needed to use a slightly different/modified view.phtml, list.phtml and page template for specific category, so I found the following solution:

I had used the following code (which I inserted in Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Custom Layout Update) and I set up the option: **Applay to Product** to **Yes!**

Here is my 1rst part of code and explanation:

```
<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/list_custom.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Above code is working great and because I wanted to have a slightly different **list view templajt** I created a new file called **list_custom.phtml** and there make some changes.

Here is my 2nd part of code and explanation:

```
<reference name="product.info">
<action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/view_custom.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Also, above code is working great and because I wanted to have a slightly different **view templajt** I created a new file called **view_custom.phtml** and there make some changes. This is OK!

I, also, use the following code:

```
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/custom_list.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

**Here is where I need help :(**

Above code is listening all the products as I want to, but when I click on the product I want that product (from specific category) to have different/custom page layout! Now, it is opened in **custom_list.phtml** templejt.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `product id` in your layout, you can use the following layout handle to make modification to your page for this specific product:

```
<catalog_product_view_id_productid>
```

Or using the `product sku`, you can use the same method with the following layout handle:

```
<catalog_product_view_sku_productsku>
```

For more reference check : [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107461/magento-2-replacement-for-the-product-type-simple-product-type-configurable/107462#107462)

Comment: I will try this, but quick question, please? What if I want to show not only one specific product, but all the products from specific category?

Comment: @user15151 I have not idea for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Create plugins for the list and view blocks.
So for the product_list block, you would create a **di.xml** file in a module with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="your_module_catalog_productlist_block_plugin" type="Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProductPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create a plugin file **app/code/Your_Vendor/Your_Module/Block/Catalog/Product/ListProductPlugin.php** with these contents:

```
<?php    
namespace Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Block\Catalog\Product;

use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;

class ListProductPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject
     */
    public function beforeToHtml(ListProduct $subject)
    {
        if (/*Your conditions go here*/) {
            $subject->setTemplate('your_template_file.phtml');
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

For the other blocks you would add another  element in the di.xml file and create a similar plugin class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rimšiakas, thank you for your replay. To be honest, I can't follow your :(

Comment: https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system/
In this link you'll find a pretty good explanation on how to work with plugins, in case that's the problem.

Comment: Great, I will take a look at it. Thanks one more time.