# How to unset block from container in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to unset the block assigned to the container. For example, `catalog.compare.sidebar`. It is defined in the layout in the following way:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.compare.sidebar"
           template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/sidebar.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="compareProducts" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/compare-products</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">catalog.compare.sidebar</argument>
    </action>
</referenceContainer>
```

But this doesn't work, because `sidebar.additional` is a container. How can I unset the block?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

If you want to remove something use remove="true", 
If you want to move something use move.
In Magento 1 unset was used to move Blocks, cause we had no move Statement. But after unset you had to add the Block back again at its destination. So 2 Instructions necessary. Magento 2 only move is necessary (1 instruction).

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 it's much easier to move an element, you need to use the [move instruction](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv)

**Unset/move**

So you would write:

```
<move element="catalog.compare.sidebar" destination="block-to-move-to" />
```

**Remove**

If you mean you'd like to remove it completely then you would write:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Maybe not so clear Unset/move
Unset(Magento 2) ->  in Magento 2 -> remove="true" 
Unset and set it at other location in Magento 1 (with unset) in Magento 2 -> move.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want to move the block, I would like to unset the core block, and then insert it using "ifconfig" attribute. So I can control the visibility of the core block depending on the configuration setting.

Comment: if you want to make it visible again just change remove="true" to remove="false"

Comment: @SamirShaban I am not talking about removing here

Comment: you want to display the Block depending on the ifconfig condition. As far as i know ifconfig doesnt work with move. So simple solution would be remove it with remove="true" and then add it back with your ifconfig condititon. See this post http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85032/magento-2-ifconfig-in-layout-xml